# Cant deploy GAE-project on app engine

Tags: google-app-engine

When I try to deploy my GAE project to app-engine I get the following error on the site that is brought up:

```
Error: Server Error
The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.

Please try again in 30 seconds.
```

Ive been getting this error all day. My friends run the same project without a problem.

code in appengine-web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
<application>mySiteName</application>
<version>1</version>
...
```

Url that shows when page is loaded:

```
http://1-dot-mySiteName.appspot.com/
```

"1-dot-" is only for me, my friends dont get this, maybe that is why? But I have no idea what to do to remove it or make it work. something in properties? please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Study your app Versions page in the [AppEngine Dashboard](https://appengine.google.com/).  The versions are determined by `appengine-web.xml` when you deploy.  Developers can concurrently deploy any number of versions side by side.  Their URLs will be `http://1-dot-mySiteName.appspot.com/`, `http://2-dot-mySiteName.appspot.com/` and so on.  They are online concurrently and share a single set of Datastore content.  Only one of them will be the default version, and that one has the privilege of bearing the domain name `http://mySiteName.appspot.com/`.

Your deployment errors have nothing to do with this.  There must be something wrong with your copy of the project.  Back up your current files, and restore an earlier version that worked.  Edit `appengine-web.xml` to change the version number to something new for the reasons described above and try a deployment.  Keep going back to earlier or simpler project files until deployment works.  Then copy your latest changes into your new version that does deploy, little by little, testing deployment one change at a time.  Finally make your new version the default version after everything works correctly.

Answer (score 3):

This error happened to me when I used Java 8 instead of Java 7, which is currently supported by App Engine.

In errors of my app on AppEngine Console I saw this:

```
Uncaught exception from servlet java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/apache/jsp/guestbook_jsp : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 at com.go
```

You can check your java version:

```
$ java -version
```

This is solution:

Then go to profile:

```
$ vim ~/.bash_profile
```

And change your JAVA_HOME variable:

```
export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.7`
```

Update that variable:

```
$ source ~/.bash_profile
```

And now rebuild your AppEngine project and redeploy it on server:

```
$ mvn clean install
$ cd guestbook-ear
$ mvn appengine:update
```

Now check your application on browser: https://.appspot.com/

Answer (score 0):

If you are using eclipse plugin to deploy, check your java build information.

Eclipse -> Window -> Java -> Compiler -> Compliler compliance settings
It should be 1.7